# Rails - Trying to check if a column is empty before adding rows into table using .present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a table that shows a list of prescriptions.  I want to filter out prescriptions that do not have an "ended" date.  I'm trying to use present? but not having any luck.

```
  <% if @prescriptions.where(:ended => present?) %>
  <% @prescriptions.each do |prescription| %>
      <tr>
        <td><i class="fa fa-medkit"></i> <%= prescription.drug.friendly_name %></td>
        <td><%= prescription.dosage %></td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <%= prescription.started %></td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <%= prescription.ended %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you indicated what error you're getting and which controller action is rendering this view.

You could use a select to filter out prescriptions with no end date, but what would be better is to set up a scope in your model. Assuming you have a model for prescriptions:

```
def self.unexpired
  where.not(ended: nil)
end
```

The controller could call this scope e.g.

```
Prescription.unexpired
```